# Info on boot screen

Tags: boot, 20.04

When I boot ubuntu, I get the following loading screen:

[image: Loading screen]

How do I fix this, apart from it being annoying I don't know what is wrong with my machine.

Comment: Just to confirm, eventually the loading screen disappears and you can use your computer normally, isn't it?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi yes, this is something that just shows up, for a moment, and then it goes away, but it is annoying and I want to fix it. I'm sure there's a way, I just don't know what's wrong.